# EditActionsForRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: objective-c

I want to make 2 buttons in tableView cell swipe and i override the method
editactionsforrowatindexpath

and it simple not work. With iOS 9.

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}



-(NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        // Logic
                                    }];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //arbitrary color

    UITableViewRowAction *button2 = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Send SMS " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                     {
                                         // Logic
                                     }];
    button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return @[button, button2];
}
```

Comment: Show the *exact* code.

Comment: Write your code that you have tried

Comment: I noticed that when i click Fun button and press the method name it does not jump to the declaration, may be its connected to the problem

Comment: on which version of ios you are runnning this?

Comment: the minimum ver of the project is 8, and the iPhone is ver 9

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,

the problem was the the DataSource Delegate and the TableViewDelegate was at 2 diffrent classes